# Datepicker don't closes after picking same date GWT

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, datepicker

I am calling java from java-script to close the date picker pop Up using following method.

```
    private native void attachInternal() /*-{+      
    $wnd.jQuery("div.datePickerDay.datePickerDayIsValue").on( "Click", function() {
       this.@com.booxi.admin.client.common.ui.text.DateFormatter::uiDatePickerPopup.hide();

      console.log("OK");
    });
}-*/;
```

this method is again called in the method attached.

The problem is that date picker doesn't closes after selecting same date which is already selected, but on value change it closes.I want to close it even after selecting same date as earlier.
The attach method is following

```
    public void attach() {
    attachInternal();

    datePickerValueChangeRegistration = uiDatePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
            uiDatePickerPopup.hide();
            uiTextDate.setErrorVisible(false);
            uiTextDate.setTextNoFormat(Moment.moment(event.getValue()).format("L"));
        }
    });

    textDateClickRegistration = uiTextDate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //if (uiTextDate.isReadOnly())
            //  return;
            if (!uiTextDate.isEnabled())
                return;
            showPopup();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSNI is wrong: you're getting a method reference to the `hide()` method, but not actually calling it. Also, the `this` inside the callback is probably the HTML element, and not the class this method pertains to (and finally, `click` might have to be all lowercase –I don't know jQuery though, so I might be wrong).

It should thus read:

```
private native void attachInternal() /*-{
  var that = this;
  $wnd.jQuery("div.datePickerDay.datePickerDayIsValue").on( "click", function() {
    that.@com.booxi.admin.client.common.ui.text.DateFormatter::uiDatePickerPopup.hide()();
    console.log("OK");
  });
}-*/;
```

Comment: I got it what you are saying. But still after this it doesn't work.it doesn't call the method

Comment: Ha! That `this` is probably not what you think it is! Updated my answer.

Comment: No its not working out.I am not able to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but maybe it helps if anybody has the same problem.

I made the same error. The problem is, the change event only fires if a different value is selected. If the user selects the same value again, then there is no value change, the event does not fire, your code is not executed and the popup does not hide.

You have to use a click event instead of the value change event. Then by every click, even on the old value, the code is executed. But if you just replace the change event with the click event, then the code also is executed when the user clicks on the header of the date picker, for example when he clicks on the arrows to choose a different month. This would brake the functionality of the date picker.

So in the click event you have to check if the click is really in a date cell and not in the header. This can be done with `Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget())` and check the element's content, easiest check if the inner text is a date number between 1 and 31.

So the code is like this

```
uiDatePickerPopup.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Element target = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
    String targetContent = target.getInnerText();
    try {
      int d = Integer.parseInt(targetContent);
      if (d >= 1 && d <= 31) {
        uiDatePickerPopup.hide();

        ...
        enter the rest of your code here
        ...

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      /* ignore, click was not on a date cell */
    }
  }

}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

(As far as I know there is no more elegant solution. The other possible events are not useful, and you can't restrict the click event only to the date cells, because the `getView()` method is `protected` and the underlying `CalendarView` is `final` and can't be extended to a subclass providing the necessary check for the content.)